# Average vs Worst-Case Hitting Time

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, random-walks

Consider a simple random walk on an undirected graph and let $H_{ij}$ be the hitting time from $i$ to $j$. How much bigger can 
$$ H_{\rm max} = \max_{i,j} H_{ij}, $$ be compared to 
$$ H_{\rm ave} = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n H_{ij}.$$ For all the examples I can think of, these two quantities are of roughly the same order of magnitude.

To make this into a formal question, define 
$$\phi(n) = \max_{\mbox{undirected graphs with } n \mbox{ nodes }} \frac{H_{\rm max}}{H_{\rm ave}}.$$ How fast does $\phi(n)$ grow with $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quantity $\phi(n)$ grows like $\Theta(n)$.

For the lower bound, consider the following graph: a clique on $m$ vertices connected to a path of length $k = C\log m$ for an appropriate $C$ (so $n = m + k \approx m$), in which each vertex of the path is also connected to the first vertex of the path (the one incident to the clique). The maximal hitting time is some large number $M = \exp(k)$. The hitting time of two vertices in the clique is around $m \ll M$. The hitting time of a vertex on the path and any other vertex is at most $M$. So the average hitting time is at most roughly $m + \frac{2kn}{n^2} M = O(kM/n)$. In fact, the hitting time of a vertex at distance $t$ from the clique is roughly $\exp(t)$ (for $t \gg \log m$), and if we take this into account then we get an average hitting time of roughly $m + \sum_{t=1}^k \frac{2n}{n^2} \exp(t) = O(M/n)$. This shows that $\phi(n) = \Omega(n)$.

For the upper bound, let $H_{ij}$ be the maximum hitting time. The triangle inequality shows that for each $k$, either $H_{ik} \geq H_{ij}/2$ or $H_{kj} \geq H_{ij}/2$. So at least $n/2$ of the hitting times are at least $H_{ij}$, showing that the average hitting time is at least $H_{ij}/n$. This shows that $\phi(n) = O(n)$.

Comment: Could you explain why the maximal hitting time is around $3^k m$?

Comment: This particular number could be wrong, but the maximal hitting time should be large. I got $3^km$ since in order to get to the end of the path, you must go towards the end of the path $k$ times in a row. Each time you go to the clique you take time $m$ to try again. This doesn't quite give $3^km$, but the exact number isn't important as long as it's much larger than $m$ (and exponential in $k$).

Comment: I don't understand where the exponential hitting time comes from. It cannot be the case for large $C$, as hitting time between two nodes at distance $k$ is always at most $kn^2$ by the commute time formula.   Note that when you add edges connecting every vertex to the vertex adjacent to the clique, these edges can be used in both directions. I do agree with the conclusion, and the lower bound can be simplified by just having a single edge outside the clique.

Comment: Probably a mistake on my side.

Answer (score 3):

This is an addendum to the answer by Yuval Filmus. Indeed $\phi(n)=\Theta(n)$, and the upper bound is explained in that answer. I don't understand the argument for the lower bound given there, but a simpler graph will yield the required bound. Let $G$ consist of a clique of $n-1$ vertices, where one of them, say $x$, is connected to one additional vertex called $y$. Let $f(v):= E_v \tau_y=H(v,y)$ denote the expected hitting time from $v$ to $y$. Then, by conditioning on the first step and using symmetry,
$$ \forall v\notin\{x,y\}, \quad  f(v)=1+\frac1{n-2} f(x) +\frac{n-3}{n-2} f(v)$$
and
$$f(x)=1+\frac{n-2}{n-1} f(v) \,.$$
Solving these linear equations gives $f(v)=(n-1)^2$ and $f(x)=n^2-3n+3$.
On the other hand, only $n-1$ of the $n(n-1)$ mean hitting times are of order $n^2$,
(namely when the target is $y$). The mean hitting time of every target vertex  in the clique is less than $2n$, so $H_{\rm ave}=O(n)$.